# Why does this material show up black?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

[image: Texture will not show :c]

[image]

So basically I was rigging up the new CS:GO hands in a multirig,as you do, and after all the rigging was done and textures were assigned, I went to do a render in Cycles to see the end result. In the view port, the textures showed fine, however, as soon as I rendered, they showed up as just blackness. My nodes are all set up as they should be, and it's not the lighting in the scene as you can see, other textures do still show. I think it may be something to do with the mesh itself by I've exhausted all my ideas.

If anybody has any idea what it could be, please let me know!

Comment: You should upload your blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post the link here, so it's easier for others to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Is the final result of your node setup plugged into the *Material Output* node?  Or do you have multiple Material Output nodes?

Comment: Hi... At least as you have your Blender file loaded, the suns have been turned off for rendering.. meaning they are not contributing light to the scene. The textures were not packed with the file, but if I make the arms a default material, they seem to show up well....